# Run a script for every SID that has logged into computer (Batch script)

Tags: batch-file, registry, sid

So, I'm trying to go into the registry and delete all of the HKCU keys listed. I have it setup to delete all of the keys for a specified user's SID, however I'd like to automate it and have it remove the keys for all users. The script has to be run as admin, and due to a windows update from a year or so ago, I need to run this script about once a month to prevent the need to provide admin rights for each user affected.

```
@ECHO off
SET /p SID=Type in user's SID:
ECHO User SID:%SID% > LOG.txt
REG DELETE HKEY_USERS\%SID%\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Products\452033ab5697de740950c3bbe5df23ab /f >> LOG.txt 2>&1
REG DELETE HKEY_USERS\%SID%\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Products\48a13d91454582b4faf744a91b0c2c9b /f >> LOG.txt 2>&1
REG DELETE HKEY_USERS\%SID%\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Products\9c3c61d27303d6049a12e160ccfbc300 /f >> LOG.txt 2>&1
REG DELETE HKEY_USERS\%SID%\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Products\aa7f2c2a1b079f34488e76ab87eeac10 /f >> LOG.txt 2>&1
REG DELETE HKEY_USERS\%SID%\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Products\b298dde705552b440ae8d40b79981a81 /f >> LOG.txt 2>&1
REG DELETE HKEY_USERS\%SID%\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Products\ca3d13757e7568c4da4a745d1c7c6faa /f >> LOG.txt 2>&1
Exit
```

I've found a script to grab every user withing the active directory....but with our firm, that's a *lot* longer than doing this on computers with either individual users, or shared among 5 or less individuals.

I know that the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

Has a list of all of the SIDs, but I'm not sure how to use each subkey name as a variable, and then run (maybe a loop) with each variable in turn.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for /f "tokens=3*" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /f ProfileImagePath /s^|findstr /v /i /c:"(es)"') do Echo your command on %A%B
```

For loops are designed to do command output parsing.

Use `%%A` in a batch file (I used `%A` for interactive typing so you can paste into a command prompt)

Use `%A%B` as this will handle paths with spaces.

Escape the pipe (`|`) with caret (`^`)

`Findstr` removes the last line (number of matches found)

See `for /?`, `reg /?` and `reg query /?`, and `findstr /?`.

**OR ask the system admin to configure windows to only keep x number of profiles or not store roaming user profiles at all**.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Maybe I'm just tired, but I've fiddled around with it a bit and it keeps crashing immediately after launch. Tried throwing in some pauses, but it's still a no go.